# Is there any batch command to move files and delete empty sub folders

Tags: command-line, command

Anyone know of a simple batch command to move files and delete empty sub folders? Just got a new external and when I copied everything over it resulted in something like this. F:\Music\John Denver\John Denver\files1-10 F:\Music\TheBeatles\TheBeatles\files1-10 and so on, for say, 350+ folders. I don't want to waste that much time manually moving them up one folder and deleting sub folders... Not all files are same file type, and not all folders are music. Some folders have other sub folders that I want to keep (mostly for music files, such as artist\album\files) Is there a way to do this instead of the old fashioned way? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ROBOCOPY.

```
ROBOCOPY source destination /S /MOVE
```

/S flag is used to exclude empty subfolders.

```
ROBOCOPY "F:\Music\John Denver\John Denver\files1-10" "F:\Music\TheBeatles\TheBeatles\files1-10" /S /MOVE
```